# Change Server from NGINX to Apache in MAMP

Tags: apache, nginx, mamp

In my MAMP preferences, I changed the "Web Server" from Apache to Nginx. Now whenever I trying to open MAMP, it is erroring out. I want to revert my settings back to use Apache as my web server. I could not find any documentation on how to change the settings from the MAC terminal. I had MAMP set perfectly fine at port 8888 & even MySQL was running very fine.

Any help on how can I can the server settings back to Apache from Nginx without using the MAMP preferences tool [MAMP preference tool is not opening up whenever I try to open it]

Thanks,
Anirban

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: can you paste what error you get?

Answer (score 2):

It should be just a matter of changing the config file to handle it, and restarting apache.  Also, I found some code on how to enable nginx with mamp at https://gist.github.com/raamdev/8757698

the nginx conf file is nginx.conf and the apache is httpd.conf.
you should be able to search your system to find those files through the terminal.

Without seeing the error though, this might help point you in the right direction.

If all else fails, make a backup of your html files, kill mamp, and reinstall.  Shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: Thanx mate. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was able to resolve it by going to `MAMP > conf > nginx` and renaming nginx.conf to nginx_1.conf (you can rename the file to something else) and then restarting MAMP it started successfully but the web server was still Nginx just selecting Apache on the preferences screen it will change it back to Apache web server.